# How to make Ant design's Form List required?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant-design library's Form component and I want to make the `Categories` field required like the `Name` field, How can I achieve that? I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
<Form>
  <Form.Item label="Name" rules={[{ required: true, message: "This field is required" }]}>
    <Input />
  </Form.Item>

  <Form.Item label="Categories" rules={[{ required: true, message: "This field is required" }]}>
    <Form.List>
      {fields => (
        <div>
          {fields.map(field => (
            <Form.Item {...field}>
              <Input />
            </Form.Item>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </Form.List>
  </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my code and it works

```
<Form.Item
  {...layout1}
  name="checkPlans"
  label="Plans"
  style={this.state.disableField ? {pointerEvents: 'none'}: ''}
  className='requiredField'
  rules={[
     ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
     validator(rule, value) {
       if (getFieldValue('plans') && getFieldValue('plans').length) {
         return Promise.resolve();
       }
       return Promise.reject('Please add plans');
     },
     }),
  ]}
 >
        <Form.List
          name="plans"
          label="Plans"
        >
        ...

        </Form.List>
</Form.Item>
```